# Python, QRCODE - how to display the image?

Tags: python, image

I successfully generated a code, I think, using the `qrcode` library. When I run the command, it throws no errors. How can I now save the file as a `.png`?

This is the code I have so far:

```
import qrcode


qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
        )

qr.add_data("This is a test string")
qr.make(fit=True)
img = qr.make_image()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to save the image data to a file explicitly, like so:

```
with open('myfile.png', 'wb') as f:
    img.save(f)
```

Edit: apparently `qrcode` requires these packages to be installed for saving images:

> ```
> pip install git+git://github.com/ojii/pymaging.git#egg=pymaging
> pip install git+git://github.com/ojii/pymaging-png.git#egg=pymaging-png
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
I get an error message stating "ImportError: No module named 'pymaging'", 

What module do I have to install to fix that?

Comment: Added the packages as an edit. That should work now.

Comment: I get an error when I put those commands in my command prompt...

Collecting pymaging from git+git://github.com/ojii/pymaging.git#egg=pymaging
  Cloning git://github.com/ojii/pymaging.git to c:\users\floris\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-m_nax17m\pymaging
  Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q git://github.com/ojii/pymaging.git C:\Users\Floris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-m_nax17m\pymaging
Cannot find command 'git'

Comment: Cannot find 'git' means you should install git ;) See https://git-scm.com/download/win .

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working, it saved a QR-code! One final question: How can I make the name of the file variable? So I can have multiple QR-codes generated with different names.

Comment: @Cake To be honest, you might benefit a lot from reading some basic Python tutorials: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ . The `'myfile.png'` above is a string, you could replace that by a string variable (e.g., `filename = 'somefile.png'; open(filename, 'wb')...`) and manipulate that variable's contents.